# Filter HTML table data in python

Tags: python, html

I have a HTML table with multiple rows. I want to implement a possibility to filter table data by inserting filter criteria. This has to be done on server side on python. I need to avoid use of BeautifulSoup. Since my table is simplified I want to achieve this using regular expressions only.

Basically, once user clicks on a button on table page script only should show matching table rows.

Table is:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top">test67</td> //username
    <td valign="top">24-11-2016, 02:20</td> //date
    <td valign="top">1</td> //number
    <td valign="top">0</td> // number
    <td valign="top">Player win</td> // result
    <td valign="top">1</td> // time
</tr>
```

Python side:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import cgi
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
filter = data.getvalue('request')
f = open('..../stats.html', 'r+')
html = f.read()
matches = re.findall(filter, html)
f.write(matches)
f.close()
```

This is my version so far which does not parse a thing. I know it is currently wrong as `write` would only insert exact matches but could you please point out why it inserts nothing at all and also assist if there is a possibility to define gaps where `findall` will search for matches?

Comment: What is `..../` in the path there?

Comment: @Dekel Thank you for your response. This is the path to my directory on the server, I have replaced it with dots to hide personal data